# Trying to sort txt file alphabetically and saving it into a new file

Tags: python

I am able to make the text file into a list and sort it alphabetically. I am having trouble saving/inserting this new list into a NEW text file called `GirlsNamesSorted.txt`. I currently have:

```
newGirlFile = open('/Users/MacUser/Documents/Python/GirlNamesSorted.txt')

for i in newGirlFile:
    j = i.rstrip("\r\n")
    girlList.append(j)
    girlList.sort(key=str.lower)
newGirlFile.write("\n".join(girlList))
print newGirlFile.read()


newGirlFile.close()
```

I believe the error is coming from:

```
newGirlFile.write("\n".join(girlList))
```

But I am not entirely sure and need help finding the error and fixing it.

Comment: can upload your text file content?

Comment: What precisely does *"having trouble"* mean? Give a [mcve].

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: How do I insert the list into the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort your file, just do:

```
from contextlib import closing
with closing(open('/Users/MacUser/Documents/Python/GirlNamesSorted.txt', 'w+')) as newGirlFile:
    girlList=sorted([i.strip() for i in newGirlFile], key=str.lower)
    newGirlFile.write("\n".join(girlList))
```

Note: you should also use `with` syntax when writing and reading file so the file gets closed properly. In Jython, the context manager requires an additional `closing()`

Comment: This seems to make sense but I am getting an syntax saying that it is not a legal Jython

Comment: Which part does it say it's illegal?

Comment: with open('/Users/MacUser/Documents/Python/GirlNamesSorted.txt', 'w+') as newGirlFile:

Comment: Ah i see...jython requires an additional wrapper around it, try it now

Answer (score 0):

By default, [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) opens a file as read-only; you need to specify the mode, in this case `w+` for **w**riting and reading, as the second parameter.

```
newGirlFile = open('/Users/MacUser/Documents/Python/GirlNamesSorted.txt', 'w+')
```

Comment: So after I added the w+, I stopped getting an error but it doesnt print anything nor did it change the content of the file

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to read input from a file and write output to the same file.

Please crate new file to write the output as mentioned below,

```
newGirlFile = open('/Users/MacUser/Documents/Python/GirlNamesSorted.txt','r')
out_file = open('/Users/MacUser/Documents/Python/GirlNamesSortedOutput.txt', 'w')

girlList = []

for i in newGirlFile:
    j = i.rstrip("\r\n")
    girlList.append(j)
    girlList.sort(key=str.lower)

out_file.write("\n".join(girlList))

newGirlFile.close()
out_file.close()
```

Hope this will works.

Please let me know in terms of any queries.

Comment: Ah so currently, the GirlNamesSorted.txt is a blank page.

Comment: I think you committed mistake somewhere, because  we opened the file only as read only mode, so it is impossible for modification of file during execution.

Comment: Oh you are right! It works fine now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
oldGirlFile = open('/Users/MacUser/Documents/Python/GirlNamesSorted.txt', 'r')
girlList = [line.rstrip("\r\n") for line in newGirlFile.readlines()]
oldGirlFile.close()

girlList = girlList.sort(key=str.lower)

newGirlFile = open('/Users/MacUser/Documents/Python/GirlNamesSortedNew.txt', 'w')
newGirlFile.write("\n".join(girlList))
newGirlFile.close()
```

Then you can open the file in your text editor and check its content.

Comment: I got an error saying "An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function."

Comment: Can you be more specific?  In what line did the error happen?  Or when calling what function??